# Как позиционировать input z-index в md tabs?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, angularjs, material-design

День добрый, друзья!
Используя скрипт Angular-intro, в md-tabs, возникает проблема input выделяется, но его z-index почему-то меньше, чем надо, тем самым не получается его мышкой выделить. В чем дело?

Мое предположение: почему то не срабатывает свойство `.introjs-showElement {z-index:999999 !important;}`, которое добавляется к элементам лежащим в md-tabs
P.S. Если использовать без md-tabs все отлично.

Прикладываю наглядный пример: [codepen.io/zircon163/pen/vGpyMO](http://codepen.io/zircon163/pen/vGpyMO)

Заранее огромное спасибо!